Repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied. Also there's "insufficient_scope" error
Complete error:
time="2024-10-29T16:06:48Z" level=warning msg="Reason: registry responded to head request with "401 Unauthorized", auth: "Bearer realm=\"https://auth.docker.io/token\",service=\"registry.docker.io\",scope=\"repository:verax5/sixthdesk:pull\",error=\"insufficient_scope\""" container=/sixthdesk_backend image="verax5/sixthdesk:latest"
time="2024-10-29T16:06:49Z" level=info msg="Unable to update container "/sixthdesk_backend": Error response from daemon: pull access denied for verax5/sixthdesk, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied. Proceeding to next."
time="2024-10-29T16:06:50Z" level=info msg="Session done" Failed=0 Scanned=3 Updated=0 notify=no
I've tried to login already:
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:/var/www/html# docker login
Authenticating with existing credentials...
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credential-stores
Login Succeeded
Docker ps output:

